# Ajaxform submit giving an undefined alert

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I have a `ajaxform submit` function that is being called when a form is being submitted.But when i click the `submit button` in that `form` i get an `undefined alert`.I get this issue in `IE9`.I can't find this issue in `chrome` and `firefox`.Could someone help me solve this.Thanks in advance.. :)

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm({
    var fname = $('#testimonial_send #name').attr('value');
    var myemail = $('#testimonial_send #email').attr('value');
    var mymessage = $('#text').attr('value');

    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: fname,
        email: myemail,
        message: mymessage,
    },
    success: myresult,
}).submit();

function myresult(){
   window.location.replace("homepage");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with this? `success: myresult,`

Comment: show the code for `myresult`

Comment: Are you trying for file upload??

Comment: yes.I am also performing a file upload.But i have commented the action part completely.but still i get the undefined alert message..

Comment: IE < 10 doesn't support ajax file uploads.. May be this will help you.
https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/302

Answer (score 0):

Add an error callback a see what's in there.

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm().success(...).error(..)
```